# accordion child with mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been trying to get a mega menu to work with mouseover rather then click. The drop-downs and first layer of the accordion works fine but I have a problem with the 2nd layer (child) accordions working right. I have tried different java and css solutions and they all seem to only effect the 1st layer of the accordion. The 2nd layer of accordions move to fast to be able to open and see or click on anything.
Any ideas, or suggestions would be great.

Here is a fiddle link of my code
http://jsfiddle.net/kLx6e52e/407/

```
<div id="accordion2" class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse2-1">Boat Tours</a></h4>
</div>
  <div id="collapse2-1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div id="accordion5" class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion5" href="#collapse2-2-1">Arenal Boat Tours & Safari Floats</a></h4>
          </div>
            <div id="collapse2-2-1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="Boat_Tours.php#BOAT">** All Boat Tours</a></li>
                  <li><a href="tours/Pontoon-Cano-Negro.php">Pontoon Ca&#241;o Negro</a></li>
                  <li><a href="tours/Cano-Negro-Eco-Safari.php">Ca&#241;o Negro Eco Safari</a></li>
                  <li><a href="tours/Raft-Safari-Float-Don-Pedro-Farm.php">Raft Safari Float + Don Pedro Farm</a></li>
                  <li><a href="tours/Sunset-Catamaran-Cruise-on-Lake-Arenal.php">Sunset Catamaran Cruise on Lake Arenal</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion5" href="#collapse2-2-2">Arenal Kayaking & Canoe Tours</a></h4>
          </div>
            <div id="collapse2-2-2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="Boat_Tours.php#KAYAK">** All Boat Tours</a></li>
                  <li><a href="tours/Canoe-Lake-Arenal.php">Canoe Lake Arenal</a></li>
                  <li><a href="tours/Canoe-Cano-Negro.php">Canoe Ca&#241;o Negro</a></li>
                  <li><a href="tours/River-Kayak-Safari-Float-Tour.php">River Kayak Safari Float Tour</a></li>
                  <li><a href="tours/Canoe-Safari-Float.php">Canoe Safari Float</a></li>
                  <li><a href="tours/Canoe-Tres-Amigos-River.php">Canoe Tres Amigos River</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse2-2">Sport Fishing</a></h4>
  </div>
        <div id="collapse2-2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="tours/Lake-Arenal-Bass-Fishing.php">Lake Arenal Bass Fishing</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse2-3">Watersports Tours</a></h4>
    </div>
        <div id="collapse2-3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Watersports_Tours.php">** All Watersports Tours</a></li>
                <li><a href="tours/Lake-Arenal-Extreme-Flyboard.php">Lake Arenal Extreme Flyboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="tours/Canoe-Cano-Negro.php">Canoe Ca&#241;o Negro</a></li>
                <li><a href="tours/Kayaking-Arenal-Lake.php">Kayaking Lake Arenal</a></li>
                <li><a href="tours/Canoe-Lake-Arenal.php">Canoe Lake Arenal</a></li>
                <li><a href="tours/River-Kayak-Safari-Float-Tour.php">River Kayak Safari Float Tour</a></li>
                <li><a href="tours/Canoe-Safari-Float.php">Canoe Safari Float</a></li>
                <li><a href="tours/Biking-and-Kayaking-Lake-Arenal.php">Biking & Kayaking Lake Arenal</a></li>
                <li><a href="tours/Canoe-Tres-Amigos-River.php">Canoe Tres Amigos River</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse2-4">Whitewater Rafting Tours</a></h4>
    </div>
        <div id="collapse2-4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div id="accordion4" class="panel-group">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4" href="#collapse2-1-1">Arenal Rafting Half Day Tours & Full Day Combos</a></h4>
                    </div>
                        <div id="collapse2-1-1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="Whitewater_Rafting_Tours.php">** All Whitewater Rafting Tours</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="../transportation/Smart-Connections-Deals-Pacuare-River-III-IV.php">White Water Rafting Pacuare River Class III/IV</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="../transportation/Smart-Connections-Deals-Toro-River-III-IV.php">Toro River Class III & IV</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="../transportation/Smart-Connections-Deals-Balsa-River-II-III.php">River Rafting Balsa River Class II &amp; III</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="tours/Rappel-Rafting-Combo.php">Rappel & Rafting Combo</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="tours/Costa-Rica-Chocolate-Tour-and-Balsa-River-Rafting.php">Costa Rica Chocolate Tour and Balsa River Rafting</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="tours/Canopy-and-Rafting-Balsa-River-Class-II-III-Combo-Tour.php">Canopy &amp; Rafting Balsa River Class II/III Combo Tour</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="tours/La-Fortuna-ATV-Rafting-Combo.php">ATV + Rafting Combo</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="tours/Club-Rio-Adventure-Package.php">Club Rio Adventure Package</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4" href="#collapse2-1-2">Arenal Rafting Multi-Day Adventures</a></h4>
                    </div>
                        <div id="collapse2-1-2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="Whitewater_Rafting_Tours.php">** All Whitewater Rafting Tours</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="tours/Rafting-Pacuare-Class-III-IV-Overnight-Rainforest-Excursion.php">Rafting Pacuare Class III/IV Overnight Rainforest Excursion</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="tours/Pacuare-River-Rafting-Hike-Indigenous-Visit-3-Day.php">Pacuare River Rafting, Hike & Indigenous Visit 3 Day Tour</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made edits to your jsfiddle. Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/o2hunaef/

There were few issues with your fiddle, specifically

```
$('.panel-collapse').not(target).collapse("hide")
$(target).collapse(option);
```

Changed them to

```
$('.panel-collapse').removeClass("show").addClass("hide")
$(target).addClass(option);
```

Comment: Was that a general issue with the code? I see now if you click on it, it gets weird and shows the text in the accordion without opening the accordion and the accordion child still not working right when doing the mouseover.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function() {
$(document).on('mouseenter.collapse', '[data-toggle=collapse]', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        href, 
        target = $this.attr('data-target') 
                 || e.preventDefault() 
                 || (href = $this.attr('href')) 
                 && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, ''), //strip for ie7
        option = $(target).hasClass('in') ? 'hide' : "show"

        $('.panel-collapse', '.sub-panel-collapse').not(target).collapse("hide")
        $(target).collapse(option);
})
```

});

and this

```html
<div id="accordion2" class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse2-1">Boat Tours</a></h4>
    </div>
      <div id="collapse2-1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div id="accordion5" class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion5" href="#collapse2-2-1">Arenal Boat Tours & Safari Floats</a></h4>
              </div>
                <div id="collapse2-2-1" class="sub-panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="Boat_Tours.php#BOAT">** All Boat Tours</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tours/Pontoon-Cano-Negro.php">Pontoon Ca&#241;o Negro</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tours/Cano-Negro-Eco-Safari.php">Ca&#241;o Negro Eco Safari</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tours/Raft-Safari-Float-Don-Pedro-Farm.php">Raft Safari Float + Don Pedro Farm</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tours/Sunset-Catamaran-Cruise-on-Lake-Arenal.php">Sunset Catamaran Cruise on Lake Arenal</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion5" href="#collapse2-2-2">Arenal Kayaking & Canoe Tours</a></h4>
              </div>
                <div id="collapse2-2-2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="Boat_Tours.php#KAYAK">** All Boat Tours</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tours/Canoe-Lake-Arenal.php">Canoe Lake Arenal</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tours/Canoe-Cano-Negro.php">Canoe Ca&#241;o Negro</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tours/River-Kayak-Safari-Float-Tour.php">River Kayak Safari Float Tour</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tours/Canoe-Safari-Float.php">Canoe Safari Float</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tours/Canoe-Tres-Amigos-River.php">Canoe Tres Amigos River</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
       <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse2-2">Sport Fishing</a></h4>
      </div>
       <div id="collapse2-2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
         <ul>
          <li><a href="tours/Lake-Arenal-Bass-Fishing.php">Lake Arenal Bass Fishing</a></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse2-3">Watersports Tours</a></h4>
   </div>
    <div id="collapse2-3" class="sub-panel-collapse collapse">
     <div class="panel-body">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="Watersports_Tours.php">** All Watersports Tours</a></li>
       <li><a href="tours/Lake-Arenal-Extreme-Flyboard.php">Lake Arenal Extreme Flyboard</a></li>
       <li><a href="tours/Canoe-Cano-Negro.php">Canoe Ca&#241;o Negro</a></li>
       <li><a href="tours/Kayaking-Arenal-Lake.php">Kayaking Lake Arenal</a></li>
       <li><a href="tours/Canoe-Lake-Arenal.php">Canoe Lake Arenal</a></li>
       <li><a href="tours/River-Kayak-Safari-Float-Tour.php">River Kayak Safari Float Tour</a></li>
       <li><a href="tours/Canoe-Safari-Float.php">Canoe Safari Float</a></li>
       <li><a href="tours/Biking-and-Kayaking-Lake-Arenal.php">Biking & Kayaking Lake Arenal</a></li>
       <li><a href="tours/Canoe-Tres-Amigos-River.php">Canoe Tres Amigos River</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse2-4">Whitewater Rafting Tours</a></h4>
   </div>
    <div id="collapse2-4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
     <div class="panel-body">
      <div id="accordion4" class="panel-group">
       <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
         <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4" href="#collapse2-1-1">Arenal Rafting Half Day Tours & Full Day Combos</a></h4>
        </div>
         <div id="collapse2-1-1" class="sub-panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
           <ul>
            <li><a href="Whitewater_Rafting_Tours.php">** All Whitewater Rafting Tours</a></li>
            <li><a href="../transportation/Smart-Connections-Deals-Pacuare-River-III-IV.php">White Water Rafting Pacuare River Class III/IV</a></li>
            <li><a href="../transportation/Smart-Connections-Deals-Toro-River-III-IV.php">Toro River Class III & IV</a></li>
            <li><a href="../transportation/Smart-Connections-Deals-Balsa-River-II-III.php">River Rafting Balsa River Class II &amp; III</a></li>
            <li><a href="tours/Rappel-Rafting-Combo.php">Rappel & Rafting Combo</a></li>
            <li><a href="tours/Costa-Rica-Chocolate-Tour-and-Balsa-River-Rafting.php">Costa Rica Chocolate Tour and Balsa River Rafting</a></li>
            <li><a href="tours/Canopy-and-Rafting-Balsa-River-Class-II-III-Combo-Tour.php">Canopy &amp; Rafting Balsa River Class II/III Combo Tour</a></li>
            <li><a href="tours/La-Fortuna-ATV-Rafting-Combo.php">ATV + Rafting Combo</a></li>
            <li><a href="tours/Club-Rio-Adventure-Package.php">Club Rio Adventure Package</a></li>
           </ul>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
         <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4" href="#collapse2-1-2">Arenal Rafting Multi-Day Adventures</a></h4>
        </div>
         <div id="collapse2-1-2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
           <ul>
            <li><a href="Whitewater_Rafting_Tours.php">** All Whitewater Rafting Tours</a></li>
            <li><a href="tours/Rafting-Pacuare-Class-III-IV-Overnight-Rainforest-Excursion.php">Rafting Pacuare Class III/IV Overnight Rainforest Excursion</a></li>
            <li><a href="tours/Pacuare-River-Rafting-Hike-Indigenous-Visit-3-Day.php">Pacuare River Rafting, Hike & Indigenous Visit 3 Day Tour</a></li>
           </ul>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to not have the "double mouseover" I see it's mouseover to open and also mouseover to close